# jquery can't call javascript object function at the end of animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object with a bit of jquery for visual effect.

I can access this.*whatever* inside the main animate function, but I can't access this.*whatever* from the function at the end (when animate is complete)

```
this.myDiv1 = 'myScrollableDiv';
this.myDiv2 = 'myDivToScrollTo';
this.test = 'It works';

$( "#"+this.myDiv1 ).animate({
    scrollTop: $( "#"+this.myDiv2 ).position().top - $( "#"+this.myDiv1 ).position().top
}, 500, function() {
    this.myOtherFunction();
});

this.myOtherFunction = function() {
    alert(this.test);
};
```

this.myOtherFunction is not called because I think (this) in the line this.myOtherFunction(); refers to the current jquery animate function and not the global object.

So I have tried creating a copy of (this) as a standard javascript var

```
var thisCopy = this;
```

before the animate function, then use thisCopy with all the existing vars. This works...

However, I don't want to copy (this) because I need to update the real object vars for use with other functions.

I have also tried declaring myOtherFunction as a normal variable, then calling myOtherFunction without the () and it calls the function but still doesn't give me access to the object vars.

How can I call this.myOtherFunction() after the animation is complete and have access to all of the global object variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I don't want to copy (this) because I need to update the real object vars for use with other functions.

It seems that you're concerned that at the time you need the `thisCopy` variable the original `this` has changed and you're stuck with old data.

Well, I have good news: `thisCopy` is a shallow copy of the object, not an independent variable. For example:

```
var foo = { a: 1 };
var bar = foo;
foo.a = 2;
alert( bar.a );  // alerts "2"
```

In other words it's safe to use the `var thisCopy = this;` technique.

Comment: I assumed that wouldn't work but it does. I also assumed that creating a new var in thisCopy wouldn't carry on to (this) but it does. Thanks for your help Juhana

Comment: I have done some testing with 2 of the same object on the one page (second object called a different name of course), and haven't found any issues with thisCopy. But it is a concern that because it's created the same way you create local vars that there might be conflicts later on when my code grows by a few hundred lines, and I use multiple instances of the object on a page. Should I be concerned?